# How to define "in" for a python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, compare

If I had a list of some python class that had a string field, is there a way to compare a string to a list of objects of that class using `in`? I was curious if there's a way to do something like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

bar = Foo('test')
ls = [bar]

if 'test' in ls:
    print("Yay!")
```

by modifying the `__eq__` method, or maybe even there's an `__in__` method I'm unaware of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You intuition about defining a custom `__eq__` was right. You can achieve the following, which seems to be your objective here:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, s):
...         self.s = s
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         if isinstance(other, Foo):
...             return self.s == other.s
...         else:
...             return self.s == other
...
>>>
>>> bar = Foo('bar')
>>> l = [bar]
>>> bar in l
True
>>> 'bar' in l
True
>>> Foo('baz') in l
False
>>> 'baz' in l
False
```

I also want to point out that there is the [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method, which allow you to define the membership operator's behavior (`in`). However this is a method on the container type, so here defining this method for your class `Foo` wouldn't do anything, since the `in` is applied to the list, and not its individual items.

Comment: The isinstance() method is key here, I didn't know you could do that! My class works like a dream now

Comment: Glad to help! Note that `isinstance(bar, Foo)` is more robust than `bar.__class__ == Foo`, because it also works for subclasses of `Foo`.

Comment: I don't think if there's a need to use `isinstance(bar, Foo)` because once the equation check for one side of the equation fails Python will call the other side's `__eq__`.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess about modifying the `__eq__` is correct. It's definitely one way to do this. You just need to check the value of `__eq__`'s argument with the respective attribute of your object. So as a very simple way you can implement something like following:

```
In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     def __init__(self, s):
   ...:         self.s = s
   ...:
   ...:     def __eq__(self, value):
   ...:         return self.s == value
   ...:     

In [2]: bar = Foo('test')
   ...: ls = [bar]
   ...: 

In [3]: 'test' in ls
Out[3]: True
```

Note that this `__eq__` method doesn't have any restrictions like type checking or some other error handling. If you think that they're needed in your case you can consider using `try-excep` and or other condition checking as well.

Demo:

```
In [9]: foo = Foo('test')

In [10]: bar = Foo('test')

In [11]: ls = ['test']

In [12]: bar in ls
Out[12]: True

In [13]: ls = [bar]

In [14]: foo in ls
Out[14]: True
```